# just need the explanation

Tags: php, if-statement

In the following code, without `== 0` the result shows a wrong answer (A is an odd number). and with `== 0` the result shows the correct answer. I need to know the explanation.

```
    <?php
$A = 78;

if ($A % 2 == 0) {
    echo "A is a even number";
} else {
    echo "A is an odd number";
}
;
```

Comment: You may find the [php type comparisons](https://www.php.net/manual/en/types.comparisons.php) to be useful.  According to the table, when an integer is passed in as a parameter  to an if clause, it will be evaluated as `False`.  I know the page does not explain why it evaluates to `False`, but it at least makes it clear that the behavior is expected.

Comment: please fix indentations errors on your code

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Without "==0" i.e.

```
if($A % 2)
```

evaluates to 0 becomes,

```
if(0)
```

as this is false the respective else is get executed gives you "A is an odd number".

Comment: if ($A %2 ==0)  then if (39 == 0 )  and if($A%2) THEN  if(39)...now kindly explain my mistakes , that will be better for me to understand .

Comment: also kindly  explain the meaning of  '== 0 '

Answer (score 0):

The number 0 is evaluated as false in PHP. In this case $A % 0 is 0.

In that context:

```
if ($A%0) //this is false, because it is 0 and 0 is evaluated as false
```

On the other hand, A%2 == 0 is the same as (0 == 0) and that is a true statement.

Other things that are evaluated to false include, but are not limited to: null, an empty array, an empty string an object with no variables.